# Unable to create release-build with RxJava as dependency and proguard-rules

Tags: android, android-proguard

I'm using `'compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.1'` in dependencies

I have enabled `minifyEnabled true` to obfuscate the code.

But I'm getting below error-

```
Warning:rx.internal.schedulers.NewThreadWorker: can't find referenced method 'java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView keySet()' in library class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
```

I have added proguard rules for rxjava as below-

```
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    long producerNode;
    long consumerNode;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.** {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
}
```

I have also tried `compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.3.1.0'` but still I'm getting same issue mention at top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what ProGuard rule solve this issue, but if it's not necessary to use `1.3.1`, you can use older version `1.3.0` for now. Version `1.3.1` contains only minor changes and `1.3.0` with these ProGuard rules works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in 1.3.1 and is fixed by this [PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/5602) in version 1.3.2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd gone with Lukas Novak answer, I'll change to PR 1.3.2 in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this rule in your proguard file

```
-dontwarn java.util.concurrent.**
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know.